# Junit Parametrized Test per param call

Tags: java, junit

in junit every test should run independent. For more complicated procedures u usually run setup methods. But I need something like a setup method which runde before every param.

Lets say i have a testcase like this:

```
setup()
contructor()
test1()
test2()
test3()
teardown()
```

From the execution i junit parametrized test this will end up like this with 2 params:

```
setUpBeforeClass
contrcutor called
test1 running
contrcutor called
test2 running
contrcutor called
test3 running
contrcutor called
test1 running
contrcutor called
test2 running
contrcutor called
test3 running
tearDownAfterClass
```

What I need is something called before each param. So the result would be like this(changed methods with a "()"):

```
setUpBeforeClass
contrcutor called
setupParam()
test1 running
contrcutor called
test2 running
contrcutor called
test3 running
contrcutor called
tearDownParam()
setupParam()
test1 running
contrcutor called
test2 running
contrcutor called
test3 running
tearDownParam()
tearDownAfterClass
```

I know that junit tests should be atomic but the setup-procedure per param is very expensive. Is there a way to achieve that kind of execution order?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

@Before as in the first answer only results in call before every test.
Example:

```
setUpBeforeClass
contrcutor called
before
test1 running
contrcutor called
before
test2 running
contrcutor called
before
test3 running
contrcutor called
before
test1 running
contrcutor called
before
test2 running
contrcutor called
before
test3 running
tearDownAfterClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the @Before Annotation

```
@Before
public void before() {
    System.out.println("Before every test ");
}
```

Comment: The @Before only results in an execution of the before() method before every test. I want to have an execution before each param.

Comment: I updated the question. The you can see the result and what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use per-parameters objects for more than one run, it means that you have to keep the reference to them in static field, as each test method is run on a different object.

You can also keep in static field the previous value of one of the parameters, and assuming its unique value among parameter sets, you can use it as a detector of parameters change.

This is almost what you wanted, with the small glitch that `tearDownParams()` is run after the constructor for first test for new parameters.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { 1, 4, 3 },
            { 2, 5, 6 },
            { 3, 8, 12 }
        });
    }

    static int lastP1Value = -1;

    private int p1;

    public SomeTest(int p1, int p2, int p3) {
        System.out.println("constructor");
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("    test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("    test2");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        if (lastP1Value != p1) {
            if (lastP1Value != -1) {
                // this is a bit too late (after constructor for new params...)
                tearDownParams();
            }
            setUpParams();
        }
        lastP1Value = p1;
    }

    public static void setUpParams() {
            System.out.println("  setUpParams");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownParams() {
            System.out.println("  tearDownParams");
    }
}
```